# Excel: string vs integer comparison equals TRUE, but why?

Tags: excel, string, integer, excel-2016, boolean-operations

In my Excel file I have some data that contains either a dash `-` or an integer. The data looks as follows:

[image]

Following, I wish to check whether these values are higher than some particular reference integer. I use the following (cleaned) INDEX statement to get the individual values:

`INDEX($E6:$DL6;<Row>;<Column>)`

which I then compare to the reference value (located in `DO$4` in this case), and return 1 if True, 0 if False, and with an error a dash is again printed.

`=IFERROR(IF(<Indexed value>=DO$4;1;0);"-")`

I would assume that the comparison `"-">=DO$4` would throw that error. However, for some reason, the if statement produces a `1`, meaning that the comparison is `True`.

**How is it possible that such a comparison does not produces an error?** The function written out is as follows:

`=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($E6:$DL6;1;<Column-indexer>)>=DO$4;1;0);"-")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparison of a string with a number doesn't product an error - the string (in this case a dash with an apostrophe in front of it) is always bigger.

[image]

You could put a VALUE function round the index so it would throw an error if it tried to convert a string

```
=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(INDEX($E6:$DL6;1;<Column-indexer>))>=DO$4;1;0);"-")
```

Or alternatively use ISNUMBER

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($E6:$DL6;1;<Column-indexer>)),if(INDEX($E6:$DL6;1;<Column-indexer>)>=DO$4;1;0);"-")
```

There is a slight difference - if the first formula encounters a number formatted as text, it will convert it to a number, but the second one will treat it as text.

Comment: Also doing math is possible like `+0` or `*1` to get the error ;D